# ESP8266MOD does not respond to my Uno (Custom board) AT+RST command

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, esp8266, wifi

This is my very first project with a Uno board and ESP module. I have some experience with 8051 uP. I'd like some guidance in addressing my issue.

Objective:

To connect ESP8266MOD to my wifi network and send a TCP message to my HOME_SERVER whenever required.

Hardware Module:
UNO ([Induino R5 Arduino R3 USB Clone Board](http://www.simplelabs.co.in/content/induino-r5-arduino-r3-usb-clone-board)) --> level shifter  --> ESP8266MOD

As a first step, I am trying to send AT+RST command from the Uno to the connected ESP. But there is no response from the ESP. However, I am able to notice a LED blink on the ESP, whenever there is TXD operation in my Uno.

Hardware Connection:

```
UNO - Uses USB Power supply from laptop
ESP8266MOD- Uses 3 1.5V AA Batteries

                 ||
    UNO PINS       TXD      RXD     5V GND
                    ||      ||      ||
    LEVELSHIFTER     >>RXI   <<TXO  HV,GND 
                        ||      ||          
                    RXO<<    TXI>>  LV,GND
                    ||      ||      ||
    ESP8266MOD      RXD     TXD     3.3V,GND

ESP8266MOD Settings:
    CH_PD ->> 3.3V
    GPIO2 ->> 3.3V
    GPIO0 ->> GND
    GPIO15->> GND
```

Uno Code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

const byte rxPin = 2; // Wire this to Tx Pin of ESP8266
const byte txPin = 3; // Wire this to Rx Pin of ESP8266

// We'll use a software serial interface to connect to ESP8266
SoftwareSerial ESP8266 (rxPin, txPin);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  ESP8266.begin(9600); // Change this to the baudrate used by ESP8266
  delay(3000); // Let the module self-initialize
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("Sending an AT command...");
  delay(3000);
  ESP8266.println("AT+RST");
  delay(30);
  String response = "";
  while(ESP8266.available()) {
    char c = ESP8266.read();
    response+=c;
  }
  if(response != "") {
    Serial.println(response);
  } else {
    Serial.println("Empty\r\n");
  }
}
```

Output Video: [Output video view](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B60pejPe6yiSelVtQmV0dGI5M00)

[image: logic level converter]  --> [image: ESP8266MOD]

Comment: That yellow PCB, is it possible that it already have the level shift on it ?

Comment: @AndreCourchesne No, The RX and TX are directly taken from pinout. I doubt that

Comment: Then maybe you have rx connected to rx (same for tx). I would use a continuity tester to make sure of the wirring.

Comment: @AndreCourchesne    I interchanged pin from in ESP end already. still no luck. However, with existing connection when there is TX from UNO, I am able to see LED  blink in ESP.

Comment: Then the next step to me would be oscilloscope or logic analyser.

Comment: @AndreCourchesne : What about my connections. Is it correct ??

Comment: Very hard to tell, not sure I understand the way you wrote it. If you could make a drawing would be better. Try using Fritzing to do it.

Comment: Couple of ideas... Are all of your GND tied together ? They need to.
What powered your ESP8266 3.3v ? You mention 3x AA batteries, but that totals 4.5v, not 3.3v...

Comment: @AndreCourchesne :: Started from step 0 now.. Tried loopback in UNO it worked. But, loopback from level shifter not working. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/qACko.jpg)

Comment: good move. I don't know that level shifter, you got some documentation or the schematic of it ?

Comment: @AndreCourchesne : http://www.amazon.in/Generic-Channel-Converter-Bi-Directional-Module/dp/B011ECG2MM?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=d2f6ed02-1c9d-4c8e-8474-e94a6cb1c3f1 -- This is product info..IS it the right one to use here. my intention to use it here is for converting 232 (5v) to 3.3v (ESP)

Comment: Found the original maker of that level shifter (https://www.eprolabs.com/product/logic-level-converter/)
So your diagram looks good as far as how I interpret it. Where do you take your 3.3v from ? And the converter has 2 converter slots maybe one is detective, have you tried the other one ?

Comment: @AndreCourchesne : 3.3 V is separate and given from ESP module. I physically checked voltage in multi meter and seems normal

Answer (score 1):

If it is a new ESP module, your problem is quite likely a baud rate mismatch, since you are seeing an LED response but getting no reply.

The last batch of ESP-01s I received defaulted to 115200 baud, but that is too fast for SoftwareSerial (SS). You'll need to change it to 9600. [My answer to a related question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/18647/linking-arduino-nano-with-esp8266-wifi-module/24961#24961) describes one way to change it.

You could also change it with SS. You'd have to start off SS at 115200 baud, which will usually transmit OK; just ignore the apparent garbage that comes back. Then change SS's baud rate to 9600 to match, and you should have solid communication.

These are the three commands you need to send the ESP to accomplish the change:

```
AT                             # ESP should respond "OK"
AT+RST                         # Resets the ESP
AT+UART_DEF=9600,8,1,0,0       # Sets ESP UART: 9600,N,8,1,no flow ctl
```

Note: Your module might have been preset to some other rate than 115200, in which case you'll have to try various rates until you can get an intelligible reply. Once you do, set the default rate to 9600.